# Two-body problem - point of closest approach

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I am reading through an exercise :

One of the hints to solve this problem is that at the point of closest approach the comet's velocity must be tangential only, why is this the case ?

Answer (score 4):

If the velocity vector had any radial component, then the radial position would be changing, and thus it would not be the point of *closest* approach.

The same reason the maximum or minimum of a function happens when the derivative is zero.